# How can android app (Intent.ACTION_VIEW) opens url in browser, with named window

Tags: android, browser

How can I, in Android APP, open a URL in browser with a named window?

There are many good solutions for, from Android APP, opening a URL in a browser window with the Intent.ACTION_VIEW, but is there a way to specify a target name?

The reason I need this is because there is a specific step that needs to done is a browser, instead of in my APP. If a new browser window is opened every time, there will be multiple browser windows open. What I need is just using one fixed browser window.

To make it clear, below are two similar situations when open another browser window with a link. What I need is the latter one.

```
< href="url" target='_blank'&gt; Pop open a new window each time clicked.</>;

< href="url" target='MyWindow'&gt; always open in the same window</>;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should be using a `WebView` for this. There are *many* browsers for Android, plus plenty of non-browser apps that respond to `ACTION_VIEW`.

Comment: I am already heavily using webview, but what I need to do is best done in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you're trying to achieve is only possible through a custom webview or a 3rd party library. I would recommend [Chrome Custom Tabs](https://developers.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs) though because many mobile browsers actually do implement those and they offer much flexibility. Also some websites block features when they're shown in webview. For example you cannot use Google login in a Webview. You need to launch a browser or a custom chrome tab.